# Convert SQL CLR Project from VS 2010 to VS 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, sqlclr

I have a SQL CLR project that was created in Visual Studio 2010 that I am trying to open in Visual Studio 2012.  The `UpgradeLog.htm` file shows a successful migration but when I try to reload the project I get these errors in the Visual Studio output console:

> error  : Visual Studio has encountered an unexpected error.
>
> error  : The given path's format is not supported.

The only options available are to reload the project or edit the .vbproj file.

Things I've tried:

1. Searching Google for a solution.
2. Tried on multiple machines, same result.

**Any idea how to fix this?**

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I have rebuilt the projects from scratch when I migrated, as the automatic migration tool does not appear to work as expected for older SQL CLR projects.

Create a fresh SQL CLR project and re-add each of the code files - this can painstaking but it's the safest method for ensuring that you have a valid .csproj file at the end of the process.